# Do you lose the respective trading cards when uninstalling a steam game?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

These days I want to uninstall some games to get more space for the new ones.

I have earned some trading cards playing those games I want to uninstall, but I don't know if uninstalling will make me lose my trading cards of these games. Will this happen? Or I can uninstall without any problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No, trading cards are items stored in your inventory

If you uninstall a game, the cards you've already collected will remain in your inventory.

Additionally, any progress you've made towards collecting cards and the total you've earned out of the available gifted free cards from playing will be preserved. For example, if you have collected 3 out of 4 available "free" cards that can be earned by playing a game when you uninstalled it, reinstalling the game in the future will allow you to collect the one remaining "free" card.

Comment: Additionally, you won't lose your achievements or hours played.  In fact, for steam-cloud enabled games, you shouldn't even lose your save games!  In theory, at least; it's been hit-or-miss for me...

Comment: And sometimes if you have many saves, it only picks one, which is usually some wrong test save..

Comment: You can also own Cards for games you dont own. You wont lose any Card on deinstalling a game.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you uninstall a game, or Steam, you will not lose your cards. This information is stored in the cloud.